# vba msaccess tabledef item not found in collection

Tags: excel, vba, ms-access

I want to import multiple xls-files into a MsAccess-database.
The files have different headers, so they have to be imported into a different table depending on the prefix.

I get a Run Time Error 3265 – Item Not Found In This Collection, but I can't find the issue why.
When I check if the table exists, it does.

```
Option Compare Database

 Public Function ImportFiles()
 
 Dim strFolder As String
 Dim db As DAO.Database
 Dim qdf As DAO.QueryDef
 Dim strFile As String
 Dim strTable As String
 Dim strExtension As String
 Dim lngFileType As Long
 Dim strSQL As String
 Dim strFullFileName As String
 Dim varPieces As Variant
 Dim check As Boolean 'Debug:

 With Application.FileDialog(3) ' msoFileDialogFolderPicker
      .AllowMultiSelect = True
      .Title = "Please select one or more files"
      .Initialfilename = "*.xls*"

     If .Show Then
         'strFolder = .SelectedItems(1)
         strFullFileName = .SelectedItems(1)
     Else
         MsgBox "No folder specified!", vbCritical
         Exit Function
     End If
 End With

 strFile = Dir(strFolder)

 Set db = CurrentDb()

 strFile = Dir(strFolder & "*.xls*")
 Do While Len(strFile) > 0
    strTable = DetermineTable(strFile)
    'Debug:
    check = TblExists(strTable)
    
     strSQL = "UPDATE [" & strTable & "] SET FileName=[pFileName]" & vbCrLf & _
    "WHERE FileName Is Null OR FileName='';"
    Set qdf = db.CreateQueryDef(vbNullString, strSQL)
 
    varPieces = Split(strFile, ".")
    strExtension = varPieces(UBound(varPieces))
    Select Case strExtension
        Case "xls"
            lngFileType = acSpreadsheetTypeExcel9
        Case "xlsx", "xlsm"
            lngFileType = acSpreadsheetTypeExcel12Xml
        Case "xlsb"
            lngFileType = acSpreadsheetTypeExcel12
    End Select
    strFullFileName = strFolder & strFile
    DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet _
            TransferType:=acImport, _
            SpreadsheetType:=lngFileType, _
            tableName:=strTable, _
            FileName:=strFullFileName, _
            HasFieldNames:=False
           
    'Debug:
    check = TblExists(strTable)
    Set tdf = db.TableDefs(strTable)
 
     If FieldExistsInTable(strTable, "FileName") = True Then
        'Do nothing
     Else
        tdf.Fields.Append tdf.CreateField("FileName", dbText, 255)
     End If

    qdf.Parameters("pFileName").Value = strFile
    qdf.Execute 'dbFailOnError

    strFile = Dir
 Loop

     Set fld = Nothing
     Set tdf = Nothing
     Set db = Nothing
     'rstTable.Close
     Set rstTable = Nothing

End Function

Public Function FieldExistsInTable(strTableName As String, _
                                    strFieldName As String) As Boolean
 
    Dim strDummy As String
 
    On Error GoTo FieldDoesntExist
    strDummy = CurrentDb.TableDefs(strTableName).Fields(strFieldName).Name
    FieldExistsInTable = True
    Exit Function
 
FieldDoesntExist:
    FieldExistsInTable = False
 
End Function

Public Function TblExists(strTableName As String) As Boolean
    
    On Error Resume Next
    Dim tdf As TableDef
  
    Set tdf = CurrentDb.TableDefs(strTableName)

    If Err.Number = 0 Then
        TblExists = True
    Else
        TblExists = False
    End If
End Function

Public Function DetermineTable(strFile As String) As String
    If Left(strFile, 1) = "1" Then
        strTable = "RawData1"
    ElseIf Left(strFile, 1) = "2" Then
        strTable = "Raw2"        '
    ElseIf Left(strFile, 1) = "3" Then
        strTable = "RawData3"        '
    ElseIf Left(strFile, 1) = "4" Then
        strTable = "RawData4"   '
    Else
            
    End If
    DetermineTable = strTable

End Function
```

Comment: `strTable = "Raw2"` should that be `strTable = "RawData2"` like the others ? What is the prefix ? `If Left(strFile, 7) = "1"` is comparing a 7 character string with 1 character string.

Comment: Maybe you want `If Mid(strFile, 8,1) = "1"`

Comment: I changed the function strTable just for the question, it has to be left(strFile, 1).
I changed it in the original question.

The problem isn't there.  It has something to do with the Set tdf = db.TableDefs(strTable).
I got the code running by adding again Set db = CurrentDb() before the tdf-line.
It works, but I don't think it is like it should be (2 times same line of code).